# join two keys of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

is there a better way to join two keys of a  dictionary  using join() ?

dic:

```
[{'BlockType': 'LINE', 'Confidence': 99.82125091552734,
                   'Text':'abc', 'Page': 1},

{'BlockType': 'LINE', 'Confidence': 99.82125091552734,
                   'Text': 'xyz', 'Page': 2}]
```

Sol : `final = dic[0]['Text'] + dic[1]['Text']`

can we do this using a join ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = [{'BlockType': 'LINE', 'Confidence': 99.82125091552734,
                   'Text':'abc', 'Page': 1},

     {'BlockType': 'LINE', 'Confidence': 99.82125091552734,
                    'Text': 'xyz', 'Page': 2}]

print( ''.join(i['Text'] for i in d) )
```

Prints:

```
abcxyz
```

Comment: imagine, i have 5 dictionaries in `dic`,  i want to start from the index 1 but not 0

Comment: @pylearner If I understand you well, you can do `print( ''.join(i['Text'] for i in d[1:]) )` to star from index 1.

Comment: can I get the minimum of the `Confidence` from so and so indexes ?

Comment: @pylearner Try `index, value = min(enumerate(d), key=lambda k: k[1]['Confidence']); print(index, value)`

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas dataframe join

```
In [52]: dic
Out[52]:
[{'BlockType': 'LINE',
  'Confidence': 99.82125091552734,
  'Text': 'abc',
  'Page': 1},
 {'BlockType': 'LINE',
  'Confidence': 99.82125091552734,
  'Text': 'xyz',
  'Page': 2}]

In [53]: pd.DataFrame(dic).groupby('BlockType').agg({"Text":"sum"})["Text"].tolist()[0]
Out[53]: 'abcxyz'
```